# git branches sharing a common set of files

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I'm versioning with *git* a software project that consists in a big common part plus some files that change basing on the particular target machine:

```
+project-folder
|-cnc_sources
|  |-...(lot of common files)
|  |-specialized.cnc
|-plc_sources
|  |-...(lot of common files)
|  |-specialized.plclib
|-config
|  |-specialized.param
```

Since I'm supporting three different types of machines, my current solution is a single repo with three different branches, one for each machine, sharing a big common part except for the few specialized files.

I work cloning locally the repo for each machine/branch (this is very handy to test and deploy the software), but this solution doesn't scale very well because I have to manually keep synchronized the common part of all the branches copying the last version of the files in all the other working folders and committing also there.

I wonder if this manual work is avoidable. I also feel that there's something not right: the common files has different history and changesets among branches, and sometimes I find it confusing.

The vendor IDE needs the files in a certain place in the source tree, so I can't gather the common part in a separate folder (for example to create a subrepository).

My need would be to have N branches that share a common set of files scattered in the source tree (can't gather them), but since I'm a *git* newbie I have no idea about the best practices for my use case, so I would like to know what an experienced user would do in my shoes.

Comment: Before I modify (or delete) my answer, I would like to understand how you synchronize the common part. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Do you mean "branches" in the sense of a `git branch`? Or as three parallel folders within your working tree?

Comment: @eftshift0 Sure, I have to explain better (thanks for your patience). Once I have developed in a branch, I have to port all changed common files in the other two branches and committing the changes there as well. I do this sometimes copying the files directly in the other branches working folders, other times using a comparison utility on the working folders. I wonder if there's a clever way to manage this.

Comment: @RichardSmith I mean `git branch`. I have three parallel folders each pointing a different branch.

Comment: *Branches*, in Git, are irrelevant. Only *commits* matter. Commits contain files (as snapshots, a la tar or zip archives). Commits also contain metadata, which form a graph (a DAG). That's all there is in Git: the commits contain the files. Branch names, to the extent that they exist, are there only to help you (and Git) find *specific* commits. You can delete all the branch names without changing anything, as long as all the commits are still findable (this would generally require a few other names, such as tag or remote-tracking names).

Comment: The point of all that is that if you think of branches as being significant, using Git will make you miserable. You have two choices: stop using Git, or stop thinking about *branches*, and just think about *commits that hold snapshots*. (In your particular case, you could use Git submodules instead, but I have a separate rule about Git submodules, which is: "Submodules Are Wrong". :-) They're another source of misery, and should be avoided if at all possible.)

Comment: Can you describe the directory structure imposed by your vendor IDE ?

Comment: @LeGEC Sure! I tried to do it in the question, in the preformatted snippet `project-folder` is the root folder (containing `.git`), that contains the subfolders `cnc_sources`, `plc_sources` and `config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not doing it correctly. If I were you, I would have a `main` branch (or `common`, perhaps) where you have the shared project files.... either at the root of the project or in a directory called `common` or something like that. Also `config` dir if it's shared stuff. This is the branch where you keep on working on the common sources.

Then, from this branch you start the custom development for each machine... so, say.... `cnc` branch is started from `common` branch. You add there `specialized.cnc` and commit. You go back to `common`, the specialized file is gone. You start `plc` branch from here. Add `specialized.plclib` here. Add and commit. Now, if you switch to `cnc` you get the files for cnc, you go back to `plp`, you get the files for plc. Life is beautiful... now you can work on the separate branches and cherry-pick... and when you work in the common branch, you can merge into the machine-specific branches.

## Workflow

Now, if you are thinking that you just *can't* work on `common` because the project needs the specifics from the other branches to be able to build/test, then it becomes a problem of *workflow*.

Say you are on `cnc` and change a couple of common files and a change in the `cnc-proper` file. How do you move the changes around? Well, a simple way would be this:

```
git add the-specific-file-for-cnc
git commit -m "cnc: blah blah"
# at this point all the changes you have pending are for common files
# then you should be able to checkout common and commit there
git checkout common
git add the-common-files
git commit -m "common: blahblah"
```

Ok, so you committed in separate branches. How do you get the change that you did in `common` back into `cnc` which is where you need them? Simple enough:

```
git checkout cnc
git merge common -m "cnc: merging changes from common"
```

And the same thing for `plc`

```
git checkout plc
git merge common -m "plc: merging changes from common"
```

This is by no means the only way to deal with it but at least that should give you an idea of the kinds of tricks that you might pull off.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure (probably my git knowledge is too basic). When I develop I need all the files (common and specialized) in their relative locations to build and run tests. I'll look to the interesting idea of a `main/common` branch; if you spare time I'd be interested in the workflow (git commands) you had in mind.

Comment: Let me add a little more info to the question in terms of _workflow_